# iOS [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile] fails with error 260

Tags: ios, nsdata

When I call [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:sExportPathname options:0 error:&error] I sometimes get an error 260.  This only happens on one person's iPhone and iPad, that I know of.

The sExportPathname var is set to: "/private/var/mobile/Applications/812E11FF-675A-464F-AC39-4F43506DABF8/tmp/Time Logs-90614-180216.csv"

Here is the code.  Can anybody see anything wrong with it?

```
sExportPathname = [Globals pathForTemporaryFileWithPrefix:@"Time Logs" ext:@"csv"];
sExportPathUrl  = [NSURL URLWithString:[sExportPathname stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
sExportFilename = [[sExportPathUrl path] lastPathComponent];

// Create the exported data string
NSString *sData = @"My data in string format here...";

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [sData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[data writeToFile:sExportPathname options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
if (error != nil)
{
    // Never an error here!
    return;
}

// Try reading the file after it was written above
error = nil;
exportFileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:sExportPathname options:0 error:&error];
if (error != nil)
{
    // ERROR 260
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `sExportPathname`?

Comment: See the original post for the value of sExportPathname.  I removed the space but that didn't help.

Comment: See the edit of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe error 260 means the file was not found at the specified path. This is probably because your file path contains spaces, which will be converted to %20 by NSURL. Either resolve these entities or use a path without spaces.

**EDIT**

The problem is that you init your `NSURL` with `URLWithString:`, but the string you provide is not a valid URL string. You need to use `fileURLWithPath:`.

Comment: I tried a different pathname without spaces. Same issue. So spaces are not the issue. 

BTW, I'm not sure why somebody clicked the down-arrow on this question.